# Is there a way to change certain property in application.properties in runtime spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testcontainers

I'm using [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) to test my API.

Because testcontainers does not allow to specify the port of testcontainer, I have to connect to some random port after the creation of testcontainers.

Is there a way to reload application.properties or change ports of DB in test runtime?

I am using mongodb, spring boot, kotlin, testcontainers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: DOn't. That is what `@TestPropertySource` is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to connect to the container:

- Use [url addressing scheme](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/#database-containers-launched-via-jdbc-url-scheme)
- Testcontainers allows to run `container.getJdbcUrl()` on a container,
  however if you want to use Spring Boot auto configuration instead of
  creating connection manually, then you might use
  `@DynamicPropertySource` annotation as described [here](https://dev.to/rieckpil/write-spring-boot-integration-tests-with-testcontainers-junit-4-5-40am)